# Getting a null identity object in Blazor Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory, blazor-server-side

I'll probably get flagged as a bad question but I have to try.  I'm working on a Blazor server app that authenticates against AAD (now Entra Id) and its all SSO so there is no prompting to the user.  Authentication has worked fine for the past 6 months but stopped working yesterday morning for no apparent reason.  I am still running it on my local, its not published to Azure yet.

The authentication was scaffolded when I started the project and as I understand it, its handled through SignalR rather than HTTP Context.  Its all handled behind the scenes by .Net 6, yes?

In the LoginDisplay page, I am using `AuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync().Result` to get info like, user name, email, and roles.

```
public string UserName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    var authState = AuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync().Result;
    var user = authState.User;
    if (authState.User.Identity.Name != null && Storage != null)
    {
        UserName = authState.User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "name").Value;
        Storage.SetAsync("userName", UserName);
        Storage.SetAsync("userEmail", authState.User.Identity.Name!);
        Storage.SetAsync("IsTaxApprover", user.IsInRole("TaxonomyApprover"));
        Storage.SetAsync("IsAdmin", user.IsInRole("TaxonomyAdmin"));
    }

}
```

Now I'm getting a null object returned and can't authenticate.

[image]

Nothing has changed in the authentication and I have no custom code.  I upgraded the authentication packages to the latest version 6.0.23

[image]

What have I tried:

- I've been studying Microsoft articles like this to try and get a better understanding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0
- I've tried searching on things like "AuthStateProvider returns null" and the results all seem to focus on getting custom code to work and how to inject the auth provider at startup, neither of which is my issue.
- I checked my app registration in AAD and nothing has changed.

I desperately need some suggestions on what to check next.  Thanks.

**UPDATE #1**: @AnandSowmithiran suggested I try Fiddler.  Never used it before but I got the results.  There were a series of Application Insights 400 errors. The message in the body was `{"itemsReceived":1,"itemsAccepted":0,"errors":[{"index":0,"statusCode":400,"message":"Invalid instrumentation key"}]}`

I'm reading about App Insights Auth here but not sure if it effects user auth or not?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-ad-authentication?tabs=net

I'm will have to read it several times before it makes sense.  With Entra, maybe Microsoft is rolling out changes to how Auth works?

[image]

**Update #2**: I was able to resolve the app insights errors and this time I did notice an error.  There was a call to the Auth endpoint `GET /metadata/identity/oauth2/token?` which returned an error

> [Fiddler] The connection to '169.254.169.254' failed. 
> Error: NetworkUnreachable (0x2743). 
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network 169.254.169.254:80

That appears to be the Azure Instance Metadata Service (IMDS)  Reading up, it is a non-routable IP address that can only be used inside a vm or container in Azure.  I'm using neither so not sure why that is in play?

**Update 3**: I submitted a request to the Entra ID team to see if I could get any relevant logs.  Its a HUGE company so it may take a while to get a response.

**Update 4** I created a new app using Identity and it works .  One thing it reminded me of was the Connected Service for MS Identity.  The one in my project was not setup any longer.  I tried to reconfigure it and I keep get an error for an `unknown character in the JSON response` when it tries to setup the registered app.  I think something is f***ed up with my project.  If I can't fix it, I'll have to transfer everything to this new project which will take quite a while.  Either way I'm closing this Question.  Thanks for the assist.

Comment: Check via fiddler if any of the calls to `auth server` are failing, or throwing any exceptions.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran posted an update based on your suggestion.

Comment: The error indicates that the integration of your app with AppInsight is broken, because the `instrumentation key` is no longer valid, fix it and try. However, this may not be the reason why user authentication is failing, is the auth request going to the server - that is the first thing to check. Also, clear all your session /local storage and cookies from your browser and try again.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything that specifically mentions authentication, failed or otherwise.  I'll check on the key as you suggested.

Comment: It looks like I never setup App Insights.  I found a good SO answer that lays it out step-by-step so I'll fix that error.

Comment: I haven't found the issue right now according to your description, but you mentioned `the past 6 months`, so I want to confirm with you that if you were using a client secret in Azure AD and this secret was expired? As the default expire time is 6 month.

Comment: in the result we could see that the `isAuthenticated` property is false, and we are now using SSO, so we could say SSO authentication failed. Then in the latest update we could see network issue to `169.254.169.254`, and we could see the IP [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-token#get-a-token-using-http) which is for Azure VM to use managed identity to get user information. So I want to confirm with you that if you used managed identity in your app for the authentication? e.g. adding env variable in your client OS?

Comment: @TinyWang if you mean the secret in the AAD app registration, then no.  There are two secrets, one is user generated and it expires 12/23.  The ms identity generated secret expires 6/25.  It's much longer because its not user accessible.  The app shares it with AAD behind the scenes.  Also, I am not using a VM so I'm not sure if that IP address failure is playing a part in this.  Any communication between the app and AAD for tokens is being handled by whatever was scaffolded when I first created the app.

Comment: thanks for your reply. firstly we don't have other error messages here, so we could try to find them somewhere, for example, we might go to the event viewer to see if there were some useful information in the application event view and the system event view. and if we don't find any useful information, then based on the error message you found in fiddler, we might say there were some network issue(but I don't think so because network issue would disappear automatically if we didn't have any changes just like you said), so I'm deducing that the issue was related to SSO authenticate failed

Comment: so I want to know how we do the SSO, I mean, if we signed in with the account in another website and then we open this blazor website so that we could use SSO to finish the authentication? The next is that when I searched for the error message I found the `169.254.169.254` is used for managed identity, for managed identity, we need a managed identity instances(user/System-assigned) created in Azure portal, I want to know if you used this?

Comment: The login that is failing is ADD authentication (my AD account).  Its not using a managed identity.

Comment: could you pls create a new blazor server project in vs and choosing the microsoft identity platform when creating the project, and test if you were able to sign in this new app with your AAD account? I want to confirm if this is a network issue or it's code issue. because it's really hard to explain why my coding worked well in the past 6 month but it suddenly not work without any change.

Comment: For posterity, the answer to the can you use IMDS question is "it depends".

Most Azure PaaS offerings are built on top of IaaS VMs, so IMDS does exist. However, in some contexts the offering is set up where that access is disabled for you and only the platform gets it.

For each product, you have to figure out which case your in by going to their docs specifically.